# Jailbreak Developer iPhone with task_for_pid()

Tags: ios, macos, memory, kernel, jailbreak

1. I want use `task_for_pid()` and attach to another process and then change its memory on iOS system. I could do it successfully on OS X with the help of authorization services API, but on iOS, `task_for_pid()` always returns `KERN_FAILURE`. I need to `get task_for_pid()` function to work on jailbreak iPhone under root. As discussed in “Authentication” iOS does not provide this API, What should I do?
2. Could I run as root on iOS Simulator and how to test app required running as root?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is returning `KERN_FAILURE` because of sandbox restrictions. Your executable needs the `task_for_pid-allow` and `get-task-allow` entitlements. See [here](http://iphonedevwiki.net/index.php/Debugserver#Patching_for_process_attaching) for help on adding them to an executable.