# Is it possible, and how do I add a key-value pair into the new entitlements file when repacking an iOS application with frida gadget?

Tags: ios, provisioning-profile, codesign, frida, code-signing-entitlements

I am trying to repack an iOS Application; IPA file with the frida gadget dynamic library according to the following [link](https://labs.f-secure.com/blog/repacking-and-resigning-ios-applications/). However, i am running into a console log error when launching the application:

```
<Warning>: Unable to obtain a task name port right for pid 610: (os/kern) failure (5)
```

Thus, googling a bit, I found that a possible [fix](https://iphonedevwiki.net/index.php/Debugserver#Patching_for_process_attaching)([second link to related fix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9944451/jailbreak-developer-iphone-with-task-for-pid/10158431)) might be to add a `task_for_pid-allow` key-value pair to the entitlements file.

Editing the entitlements file by adding the key using a text-editor before re-sigining the application with the following code snippet:

```
codesign --force --sign "iPhone Developer: m*****************" --entitlements entitlements.plist  Payload/Plain\ Notes.app/Plain\ Notes
```

Resulted in a verification error when running ios-deploy as shown below:

```
Error 0xe800003a: The application could not be verified. AMDeviceSecureInstallApplication(0, device, url, options, install_callback, 0)
```

Is there a specific way to add key-value pairs to the entitlements file when repacking applications on iOS which would solve the verification error that I am getting?

Comment: Codesign is for signing binaries, not apps. Therefore you have to sign every contained binary within the app, not only the main binary. This means every framework dylib and of course the frida gadget dylib file. And finally at the end sign the main binary with the new entitlements.

Answer (score 0):

I found out how to add values to the entitlements file, use [PlistBuddy](https://medium.com/@marksiu/what-is-plistbuddy-76cb4f0c262d).

In my case, the below snippet should add the task_for_pid-allow key into my entitlements:

```
/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Add :Entitlements:task_for_pid-allow bool True" profile.plist
```

To check that it has been successfully added:

```
/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Print :Entitlements" profile.plist
```